# PHP code error. html code gives the value of keya keyb and keyc

Tags: php

php code error , this code keeps on giving use of undefined constant error..please help

```
< ? php
$d = 1;
$a = $_POST[keya];
$b = $_ POST[keyb];
$c = $_POST[keyc];
$d = $a + $b + $c;
echo $d;
 ? >
```

Comment: Remove space from `$_ POST[keyb];`. Also it should have quotes. `$_POST['keyb'];`

Comment: indeed the space is an error, but keya should be a string `'keya'` or a var $keya. $_POST[keya] does not mean anything.

Comment: @happa if you think some answer is useful for you than you should accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$d = 1;
$a = $_POST['keya'];
$b = $_POST['keyb'];
$c = $_POST['keyc'];
$d = $a + $b + $c;
echo $d;
```

You should use string keys in POST

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the form is submitted and add quotes as such:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $d = 1;
    $a = $_POST['keya'];
    $b = $_POST['keyb'];
    $c = $_POST['keyc'];
    $d = $a + $b + $c;
    echo $d;
}
?>
```